# Автоматизированное получение выписки ЕГРП из росреестра

Tags: автоматизация, росреестр

Хотелось бы полностью автоматизировать получение выписки ЕГРП.
Попытался расковырять форму, заявки, но она генерирует огромное количество аякс-запросов. Чтобы не нажал панель пытается получить очень непонятные данные, по непонятным урлам, например: http://rosreestr.ru/wps/portal/p/cc_ib_services_new/cc_ir/cc_ib_dostup_ir/!ut/p/z1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8zi3QNNXA2dTQy93QMNzQ0cPR29DY0N3Q0MAgz0w_Eq8DfUj6JEP1ABSL8BDuAI0h8FUWLo4WjoaGLkbeHq72bg6AikLYzcjAz8TaEKcFnhbURAAcgPhFxRkBsaYZDpmQ4AwCY38g!!/p0/IZ7_01HA1A42KG0790A5UIC4ML20O2=CZ6_GQ4E1C41KGQ170AIAK131G00P0=NJUIDL=/?windowName=3
Не представляю, как во всем этом разобраться. Может быть кто-то знает, как это сделать или хоть какую-то информацию?

Comment: Возможно это может Вам помочь [Росреестр](https://rosreestr.ru/wps/portal/p/cc_ib_ros_reestr/cc_documents/!ut/p/c4/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3gDQ1NHQw8TA09_EyNXA08ffycLA1MnQwNHE_2CbEdFAF1B92Q!/?PC_7_015A1H40IO42E0ILOB805B10A7000000_ru.fccland.ibmportal.spring.portlet.handler.BeanNameParameterHandlerMapping-PATH=%2FLegalDocumentCardController&PC_7_015A1H40IO42E0ILOB805B10A7000000_backURL=%2Fwps%2Fportal%2Fp%2Fcc_ib_ros_reestr%2Fcc_documents%2F!ut%2Fp%2Fc4%2F04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3gDQ1NHQw8TA09_EyNXA08ffycLA1MnQwNHE_2CbEdFAF1B92Q!%2F%3FPC_7_015A1H40IO42E0ILOB805B10A7000000_ru.fccland.i

Comment: Уже коечто! Спасибо большое!
А есть что-то еще? Примеры?

Comment: Просто в этом файле примеров нет. А ссылки все ведут на пустые страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел программу/утилиту **FGIS Downloader**, через локальное api позволяет скачать выписки из Росреестра, посмотрите может это решение вашей проблемы.

Источник: https://egrn.club/extranet/forum/forum50/10391-vypiski-po-api